# converting byte array of decimal value to hexadecimal string in java

Tags: java, parsing, hex, decimal

i m new to java. i want to convert a byte array of decimal value to hexadecimal string.
my input byte array is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -28]. i m getting 00000000000001e4 instead of 0000001e4. plz help me to solve this problem

```
 public static String ConvetToHex(byte[] decValue) 
{

    String value = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<decValue.length;i++)
    {
         value = value+ Integer.toString((decValue[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct to me.  Eight bytes should turn into 16 hex characters. You can use

```
return new BigInteger(1, decValue).toString(16);
```

but it will produce the same output.

Comment: but is there anyway to get in the specified format..?

Comment: Sure you can but you will produce a number which is meaningless as there is no way to read the value correctly.

Comment: For example in the format you suggest there is no way to tell if `1001` is `10`, `01` (as it should be) or `10`, `0`, `1` or `1`,`0`,`0`,`1`.

Comment: i wrote the same code in .NET like                                value = value + Convert.ToInt32(decvalue[i]).toString("x");                  i got the output which i mentioned.

Comment: You can write the code in Java too.  Doesn't change the fact that the format is broken.

Comment: Try the output for [1,0,1,0] and [16,16] and you will find they are the same with this format so there is no way to know what it should be.